# How to check if delete operation was made when response is of type ResponseEntity<Void> in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, response, sql-delete

I'm working on a Spring Boot project and I call a method from an external service that returns an object of type `ResponseEntity<Void>`. This method make a delete in the database and I want to check if the deleted operation was made. The code looks like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Void> resp = obj.deleteMethod();
```

Is a good idea to check if the `resp != null`? Thank you!

Comment: I would say that you don't have to check if resp is null: the ResponseEntity wrap thing for you (eg: the http response and code) and it should not be null.

Comment: In a properly implemented service, if the deletion did not go correctly an exception should be thrown which should be mapped to a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response (404 if the record to delete could not be found, 500 if something went wrong on the backend, etc.). On the client side this is often transformed back into an exception (but not the same one).